# Angular directives, am I going about this the right way?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm setting up a date picker using ngx-bootstrap's bsDatepicker, the demo shows it being set up like this:

```
<input bsDatepicker #dp="bsDatepicker">
<button (click)="dp.toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

This is fine I understand what is happening here and it works fine, but for me I do not need an input, I'm wanting to just put the directive straight on the button so that the datepicker appears below it when toggled like this:

```
<button bsDatepicker #dp="bsDatepicker" (click)="dp.toggle()">Toggle</button>
```

This does nothing when I click the button, however, if I change the click event to

```
(click)="this.toggle()"
```

Then the datepicker now works but there is a error in the console "_co.toggle() is not a function"

I'm thinking I am not quite going about this the right way and would appreciate any tips.

Comment: are you sure it's not just the syntax error? bsDatePicker and bsDatepicker are spelled differently

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work the way you expect.  you suggest that you "don't need an input", but the datepicker does;  that input is what the directive binds the selection in the datepicker to.  I don't see how this could possibly work if the binding is on a button....

Comment: did not have that in my real code, have edited to reflect my actual code

Comment: @Claies yes I see what you mean, I probably need to use input to access the value etc, and just hide it

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think this is better -

HTML:

```
<div class="date-picker-wrapper">
    <button class="btn"  (click)="dp.toggle()" >Date Range</button>
    <input type="text"
           bsDatepicker
           #dp="bsDatepicker">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.date-picker-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    input {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        height: 0;    
    }
}
```

So this results in the date picker dropping down from the button in the center and I have the input to hold the value, thanks @Claies for the tip